# SalesForce OutBound message Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported

Tags: community, c#, workflowoutboundmessage, tls

I have a listener on a ASMX webservice here is the following code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;


class MyNotificationListener : INotificationBinding
{

    public notificationsResponse notifications(notifications n)
    {

        string thissas = n.ActionId;
        GlobalMethods gm = new GlobalMethods();

        notificationsResponse r = new notificationsResponse();
        r.Ack = true;
        return r;
    }
}
```

The outbound message in Salesforce is showing failure delivery saying `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported`

What I have tried: 
**System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 ; System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;** 
But its still returning that Error, I am using a HTTPS domain how can I fix this?

Comment: This isn't really a Salesforce question. I'd ask on regular StackOverflow - what you need here is to have your webservice using TLS 1.1 or higher. The fact that the webservice is being consumed by Salesforce isn't really relevant to that issue.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Thank you for your suggestion I will ask it there then.